# Does the java code get reloaded too during orientation change?

Tags: android

I know the XML layouts get reloaded when the orientation gets changed. But does the Java code too?

Or does everything just stay the same, and only `OnSaveInstanceState`, etc get called by the android system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per android documents, When Screen rotate, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()). The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration.

So Yes java code also reloads during orientation change.

To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in which Android calls onSaveInstanceState() before it destroys your activity so that you can save data about the application state. You can then restore the state during onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState().

Answer (score 0):

You will loose data when screen is oriented because it will create a whole new activity so you have to save data use onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.   

  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");  

  // etc.  

  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  
}  

//onRestoreInstanceState  

@Override  
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  

  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.  

  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you meant by java code gets reloaded is where the onCreate and on resume methods get called upon a rotation , the answer is yes , also you can use the savedInstancestate instance to preserve data during the rotation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically when you changed the orientation to landscape or portrait, the OnCreate method of the MainActivity will be called again. And everything including initializing of the main class happens here. This is the behavior of Android while changing the orientation of the mobile/device.